# bash script read pipe or argument

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, stdin

I want my script to read a string either from stdin , if it's piped, or from an argument. So first i want to check if some text is piped and if not it should use an argument as input. My code looks something like this:

```
value=$(cat) # read from stdin
if [ "$pipe" != "" ]; then #check if pipe is not empty
 #Do something with pipe string
else
 #Do something with argument string
fi
```

The problem is when it's not piped, then the script will halt and wait for "ctrl d" and i dont want that. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.
/Tomas

Comment: you could always read only from stdin. If you want to pass input via command line then you could use `your_script <<< 'some string'` -- your script will see it as an ordinary input from stdin.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501860/how-can-bash-read-from-piped-input-or-else-from-the-command-line-argument

Answer (score 13):

What about checking the argument first?

```
if (($#)) ; then
     process "$1"
else
     cat | process
fi
```

Or, just take advantage from the same behaviour of `cat`:

```
cat "$@" | process
```

Comment: Couldn't get what I wanted working.  In fish using `test` with or without `if` or other commands to get argument list count would steal the potential piped input, and so does `echo $argv | cat | read ...`..  If I really wanted the functionality, maybe ruby's ARGF or even just any larger programming language at that point maybe, but I don't need it.  Guess I'll just force everything through as a prompt or argument for now.

Answer (score 8):

If you only need to know if it's a pipe *or* a redirection, it should be sufficient to determine if stdin is a *terminal* or not:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    # stdin is a tty: process command line
else 
    # stdin is not a tty: process standard input
fi
```

`[` (aka `test`) with `-t` is equivalent to the libc `isatty()` function.
The above will work with both `something | myscript` and `myscript < infile`. This is the simplest solution, assuming your script is for interactive use.

The `[` command is a builtin in bash and some other shells, and since `[`/`test` with `-t`[is in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/test.html), it's portable too (not relying on Linux, bash, or GNU utility features).

There's one edge case, `test -t` also returns false if the file descriptor is invalid, but it would take some slight adversity to arrange that. `test -e` will detect this, though assuming you have a filename such as `/dev/stdin` to use.

The POSIX [`tty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/tty.html) command can also be used, and handles the adversity above. It will print the tty device name and return 0 if stdin is a terminal, and will print "not a tty" and return 1 in any other case:

```
if tty >/dev/null ; then
    # stdin is a tty: process command line
else
    # stdin is not a tty: process standard input
fi
```

(with GNU `tty`, you can use `tty -s` for silent operation)

A less portable way, though certainly acceptable on a typical Linux, is to use GNU `stat` with its `%F` format specifier, this returns the text "character special file", "fifo" and "regular file" in the cases of terminal, pipe and redirection respectively. `stat` requires a filename, so you must provide a specially-named file of the form `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/fd/0`, or `/proc/self/fd/0`, and use `-L` to chase symlinks:

```
stat -L -c "%F" /dev/stdin
```

This is probably the best way to handle non-interactive use (since you can't make assumptions about terminals then), or to detect an actual pipe (FIFO) distinct from redirection.

There is a slight gotcha with `%F` in that you cannot use it to tell the difference between a *terminal* and certain other device files, for example `/dev/zero` or `/dev/null` which are also "character special files" and might reasonably appear. An unpretty solution is to use `%t` to report the underlying device type (major, in hex), assuming you know what the underlying tty device number ranges are... and that depends on whether you're using BSD style ptys or Unix98 ptys, or whether you're on the actual console, among other things. In the simple case `%t` will be 0 though for a pipe or a redirection of a normal (non-special) file.

More general solutions to this kind of problem are to use bash's `read` with a timeout (`read -t 0 ...`) or non-blocking I/O with GNU `dd` (`dd iflag=nonblock`).

The latter will allow you to detect lack of input on stdin, `dd` will return an exit code of 1 if there is nothing ready to read. However, these are more suitable for non-blocking polling loops, rather than a once-off check: there is a race condition when you start two or more processes in a pipeline as one may be ready to read before another has written.

Answer (score 6):

It's easier to check for command line arguments first and fallback to stdin if no arguments. [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is a nice shorthand instead of the if-else:

```bsh
value=${*:-`cat`}
# do something with $value
```

Comment: Would you care to provide a more complete example?  This looks like an interesting idea, but hard to understand how this might be used to solve the question.

Comment: The question didn't do anything with the input, so there's not much more to add. It creates a variable that has all arguments as it's value. If no arguments are provided it will fallback to stdin. So just use `$value` as a regular variable.