# How can bash read from piped input or else from the command line argument

Tags: bash, pipe

I would like to read some data either from pipe or from the command line arguments (say `$1`), whichever is provided (priority has pipe).

This fragment tells me if the pipe was open or not but I don't know what to put inside in order not to block the script (`test.sh`) (using `read` or `cat`)

```
if [ -t 0 ]
then
    echo nopipe
    DATA=$1
else
    echo pipe
    # what here?
    # read from pipe into $DATA
fi

echo $DATA
```

Executing the `test.sh` script above I should get the following output:

```
$ echo 1234 | test.sh
1234
$ test.sh 123
123
$ echo 1234 | test.sh 123
1234
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can read all of stdin into a variable with:

```
data=$(cat)
```

Note that what you're describing is non-canonical behavior. Good Unix citizens will:

1. Read from a filename if supplied as an argument (regardless of whether stdin is a tty)
2. Read from stdin if no file is supplied

This is what you see in `sed`, `grep`, `cat`, `awk`, `wc` and `nl` to name only a few.

---

Anyways, here's your example with the requested feature demonstrated:

```
$ cat script 
#!/bin/bash

if [ -t 0 ]
then
    echo nopipe
    data=$1
else
    echo pipe
    data=$(cat)
fi

echo "$data"

$ ./script 1234
nopipe
1234

$ echo 1234 | ./script
pipe
1234
```